# cart session duplicate the quantity

Tags: php, session

I have session stores arrays of items' informations, each items has a quantity i want when the user select the same items just increase the quantity instead of add it again.
when i increase quantity for one items it's ok, but when i increase the quantity for many items only it's ok for the first one, other are increasing but at the same time they duplicated with quantity 1

Example i choose x 3 times and y 2

x3
2 y
1y
1y

```
    //if it's the first item
if ( !isset ($_SESSION['Cart']))
    {
$CartItem = array ($I_ID,$I_Name,$I_Price,$I_img,$quantity);
$_SESSION['Cart'][] = $CartItem;
header('Location:salad.php');
}
//if the session contains items check if the item already exist 
else if (isset ($_SESSION['Cart']))
    {   
        foreach( $_SESSION['Cart'] as $y )
        {   
            if( $y[1] == $I_Name )
                { 
                    $_SESSION['Cart'][$i][4]++; //increment quantity 
                    header('Location:salad.php');
                    break;
                }

            else{
                $CartItem = array($I_ID,$I_Name,$I_Price,$I_img,$quantity);
                $_SESSION['Cart'][] = $CartItem;
                header('Location:salad.php');
                }
                $i++;
        }   
    }
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reponse is here :

{

```
    foreach( $_SESSION['Cart'] as $y )
    {   
        if( $y[1] == $I_Name )
            { 
                $_SESSION['Cart'][$i][4]++; //increment quantity 
                header('Location:salad.php');
                break;
            }

        else{
            $CartItem = array($I_ID,$I_Name,$I_Price,$I_img,$quantity);
            $_SESSION['Cart'][] = $CartItem;
            header('Location:salad.php');
            }
            $i++;
    }   
}
```

If the first item is not the same os $i_NAME you add an item that s why you have a lot of items.

I would do something like :

```
    {   

        $addItem = true;
        foreach( $_SESSION['Cart'] as $y )
        {   
            if( $y[1] == $I_Name )
                { 
                    $_SESSION['Cart'][$i][4]++; //increment quantity 
                    $addItem = false;
                    header('Location:salad.php');

                    break;
                }                    
                $i++;
        }
        if($addItem){

                $CartItem = array($I_ID,$I_Name,$I_Price,$I_img,$quantity);
                $_SESSION['Cart'][] = $CartItem;
                header('Location:salad.php');
                }
         }   
    }
```

And you render it better with reference on &$y and don t use $i++;